# how to expand variable within single quotes and would give output within single quotes using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to expand one variable in bash and would like to get result within single quotes itself.

for example , my script below includes:

```
    sqlplus -s user/password
    select sys_context
    Where schemaname = '$USERNAME'
```

I would like to expand it as:

```
   Where schemaname = 'XYZ_OWNER'
```

I tried something like :

```
   where schemaname = "'""$USERNAME""'"
```

But it is throwing me below error:

```
   where schemaname = &quot;'&quot;XYZ_OWNER&quot;&quot;'&quot;
```

Please suggest how can this be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get parameter expansion without wordsplitting, double quotes are used. Example:

```
USERNAME=fluffy
where_clause="where schemaname = '$USERNAME'"
```

This sets the variable `where_clause` to the value `where schemaname = 'fluffy'`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Accepting this as an answer!